# Referer, Connection and Accept-Encoding are denied in Firefox add-on with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, firefox-addon, http-referer

I'm sending an XMLHttpRequest on a website, but it will not work if I don't set the three `Referer`, `Connection`, `Accept-Encoding` headers.
This is the code I use to add them:

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Referer", referer);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

this is what shows up on the console:

```
Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Referer
Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Connection
Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Accept-Encoding
```

if I don't set `Connection`, `XMLHttpRequest` automatically sets the header as `keep-alive`.

What's the way to set them through my Firefox add-on? Should I change something on `permissions`? This is my `manifest.json`:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Task",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
      "cookies",
      "*://*.website/*"  
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.website/*"],
      "js": ["task.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, in latest versions of Firefox you can hook *browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders* to do the work. Those headers are forbidden for security purposes from many browser, comprehending Chrome, but it has been very discussed since we're into an add-on context: is forbidding this useful when you can simply use this workaround to do the same?